# Unexpected HTTP status code: 403 (-1) Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github

I have this error when I push my code to Github repository by Xcode

Answer (score 4):

Before answering the question you must know:

Although everyone can make a `pull request`, you **can't** just `push` to a repository. ِِYou need permission.

---

So this happened for me because in my Xcode, I was pushing to a remote that belonged to one of the *other* members ie I **didn't** have permission to push to.

You have two options:

- Ask for permission from the owner of that remote repo/fork and have them include into one of its **[`collaborators`](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/)**
- Or Simply push to a repo that you have permission like your own repo,
  using the dropdown menu encircled below (and perhaps then make a pull request from there to that branch you wanted to push to)

[image]

I usually run into this issue when I checkout directly from a **remote** branch ie I do something like:

```
git checkout -b localFromUpstream upstream/someBranch
```

And then when I commit, `Xcode` assumes that I want to push back to `upstream/someBranch`. But I don't permission to push to `upstream/someBranch`.

Comment: But what if I DO have permission, but still get this error?

Comment: I don't know then...maybe you're network isn't approved, or your password has expired...

Comment: It might have been the network. Anyhow, I solved it by changing the Git repository URL from HTTPS to SSH. Here I found a helpful [guide](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/).

Answer (score 3):

HTTP code 403 means forbidden, so it is most probably incorrect credentials. So double check your username and password etc.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Answer (score 0):

Even you can make a pull request, but can't just push to a repository. ِِYou need permission.

**Inviting collaborators to a personal repository**

1. Ask for the username of the person you're inviting as a collaborator. If they don't have a username yet, they can sign up for GitHub.
2. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
3. Under your repository name, click  Settings.
4. In the left sidebar, click Collaborators.
5. Under "Collaborators", start typing the collaborator's username.
6. Select the collaborator's username from the drop-down menu.
7. Click Add collaborator.
8. The user will receive an email inviting them to the repository. Once they accept your invitation, they will have collaborator access to your repository.